# Why does an Insectoid species that reproduce via deuterotoky still have males

Tags: science-based, reproduction, insectoid

Say you have a (sentient Hive-minded) bee-like alien, that functions pretty much like a earth bee: Builds hives, the only fertile female is the Queen, has different castes, drones are only there to be a much needed plot device

Since there is only one hive of that particular species,  have them reproduce the earth-bee way would  cause severe inbreeding. A way to get around that, is to get the Queen to have offspring via deuterotoky, but then that brings some problems... what causes that reproductive way to fail

Problem 2: **How (and why, from a evolutionary point of view) didn't they evolve to be a  female-only species yet?** (I really can't get rid of the males. They are important plot wise, since they aren't as attached to the Hivemind as the females are and it usually them that go on diplomatic missions and etc because all the females are too busy keeping the hive in one piece - and other thingies)

> Problem 3: :  to be
> asked in a separate question.  Problem 1: <really a component of
> problem 2: how to choose gender of unfertilized egs>

Can those problems be fixed from a scientific point of view, or is there a better way for that species to reproduce?

I believe this information is irrelevant, but here is some more info on the species, in case you need it.

They have a exoskeleton as well a (sorta...)internal one;

They have lungs, heart and a complex vascular system,

They are cat-sized, and the Queen is savanna cat-sized.

Their front legs are adapted for manipulating/building tools.

Comment: welcome to worldbuilding. Please, ask one question per post, as you can read in our [help].

Comment: "there is only one hive of that particular species" meaning they are already extinct, they just haven't filled in the paperwork just yet... When working with true hives, the hive IS the creature. Socially and genetically. Having just one member of a species , is an utter evolutionary deadend

Comment: @PcMan True, except, tell that to a queen xenomorph from the Alien franchise. Hell plants nick each other's genes all the time, there may be a solution in a frame challenge.

Comment: What happened to Problem 1?  Recent editing seems to have made an unfocused query even more unclear. VTRC

Comment: @elemtilas - Dutch closed this because too many questions so I hacked away 1 and 3 and put them in gray.  If you can improve the question please do!

Comment: This question definitely needs to be edited to be more focused. I *think* I know what they want and how to answer it, but it's not completely clear. Also it might be useful to replace deterotoky with something else, it's an incredibly obscure term and its hard to figure out what the author wants without looking it up.

Comment: @Willk -- Well, hopefully the OP will come along and clean the question up! I'm not too keen on "hijacking" another's question & severely editing it without express permission of the OP. Though I would recommend to the OP that you revisit the question, review the edits and improve the question yourself. To those who have voted to reopen, and to anyone considering such a vote: please don't vote to reopen until either this question is edited for focus or else you can offer a defense for why it should be reopened as originally written.

Comment: @elemtilas - well, I thought I did clean it up by stripping it down to just question 2.

Comment: based on the statement of only having a single colony, this species is effectively already extinct, but it sounds like what you're looking for is similar to what ants do, where the colony produces genetic clone males from unfertilized egg cells, but they have a high enough rate of mutation that these clones can reproduce with the queen without getting any genetic problems in the next generation. ants decide gender by the number of chromosomes, not the type (males always have odd numbers, half the number of their species' females).